# conjugate gradient with a positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on conjugate gradient to solve Ax=b when A is symmetric and positive semidefinite.

When A is symmetric and positive semidefinite, is (A+λ I), where λ is positive and I is an identity matrix, always positive definite? Then can we use (A+λ I) instead of A in CG since (A+λ I) is symmetric and positive definite?

When A is positive semidefinite with many repeated eigenvalues of zeros, are both A and (A+λ I) not full rank? How does CG behave when the matrix is not full rank?

Many thanks!

Comment: you might also consider asking this question on [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com).  There's a good chance someone there can answer you.

Answer (score 2):

If matrix **A** is positive semi-definite, then matrix **A**+λ**I** where λ>0 is positive definite.  The effect is to add λ to all the eigenvalues of **A**, so any zero eigenvalues of **A** become λ instead.  So **A**+λ**I** is always full rank.